# Is it possible to remove an item from argument list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def foo(name, *args, **kwargs):
```

I need to remove the first two arguments of `*args` in case its length (`len(args)`) is greater than two. Is it possible to do that?

Here is why I need to do that:
I've got the following function:

```
def foo(name, xml='my.xml', xsd='my.xsd', *otherfiles):
    print('name: ' + name)
    print('xml: ' + xml)
    print('xsd: ' + xsd)
    print(otherfiles)
```

I need to add an optional boolean parameter to the arguments of this function, without breaking the backward compatibility. So I change the function to this:

```
def foo2(name, *otherfiles, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('relativePath', True)
    if len(otherfiles)>0:
        xml = otherfiles[0]
    else:
        kwargs.setdefault('xml', 'my.xml')
        xml = kwargs['xml']

    if len(otherfiles)>1:
        xsd = otherfiles[1]
    else:
        kwargs.setdefault('xsd', 'my.xsd')
        xsd = kwargs['xsd']
    print('name: ' + name)
    print('xml: ' + xml)
    print('xsd: ' + xsd)
    print(otherfiles)
```

Now I test the backward compatibility by checking if the output of `foo` and `foo2` is the same:

```
foo('my_name', '../my.xml', '../my.xsd', 'file1', 'file2')
print('===============================================================')
foo2('my_name', '../my.xml', '../my.xsd', 'file1', 'file2')
```

The output:

```
name: my_name  
xml: ../my.xml  
xsd: ../my.xsd  
('file1', 'file2')  
===============================================================  
name: my_name  
xml: ../my.xml  
xsd: ../my.xsd  
('../my.xml', '../my.xsd', 'file1', 'file2')
```

As you can see, the first two items of `otherfiles` should be removed to maintain the old functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can not remove items from the `args` because it is `tuple`.  **As `tuple` is immutable**

but we can create new variable which contains items from the `args` according to our logic. And we can use new variable to next process.

**Demo1**:

```
def foo(name, *args, **kwargs):
    print "args: ", args
    print "Type of args: ", type(args)
    if len(args)>2:
        tmp_args = args[0], args[1]
    else:
        tmp_args = args

    print "Temp args:", tmp_args


print "Debug 1:"    
foo("ww", 12,3,4,4,5,6,7,7)
print "\nDebug 2:"
foo("ss", 1)


Debug 1:
args:  (12, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7)
Type of args:  <type 'tuple'>
Temp args: (12, 3)

Debug 2:
args:  (1,)
Type of args:  <type 'tuple'>
Temp args: (1,)
```

---

We can overwrite same variable name if we not need values from the variable in next process,

**Demo 2**

```
def foo(name, *args, **kwargs):
    print "args: ", args
    print "Type of args: ", type(args)
    if len(args)>2:
        args = args[0], args[1]     #- Created Same name variable.
    print "Temp args:", args
```

Comment: And kwargs? What about them?

Answer (score 2):

The following could be helpful to alter **named** arguments list before a function call.

Add an argument:

```
# The wrapper adds a named argument 'age' to the function call
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("before")
        # Add an argument to the existing list
        kwargs.update(age=4)
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("after")
    return wrapper

# Decorator replaces myFunc by a function which adds/changes the
# age argument before calling original myFunc
@decorator 
def myFunc(name, age):
    print(f"Hi {name} ! Are you {age} ?")
    

myFunc("Roger")
myFunc(name="Marc", age=33)
```

Remove elements:

```
# The wrapper removes the inappropriate arguments from kwargs
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("before")
        # Keep only expected names
        # kwargs.pop("argname") works if we know the name to remove
        new_kwargs = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in ["name"]}
        func(*args, **new_kwargs)
        print("after")
    return wrapper

# Decorator replaces myFunc by a function which filters
# argument(s) before calling original myFunc
@decorator def myFunc(name):
    print(f"Hi {name} !")

    
myFunc(tutu=40, name="Roger", toto="eeee")
```

It does not strictly answer the question but it fits with the title and somebody asked about kwargs in comments of the accepted answer.